# PHP to form string like "A, B, C, and D" from array values

Tags: php, arrays, implode, array-splice

Given the following array:

```
Array
(
    [143] => Car #1
    [144] => Car #2
    [145] => Car #3
)
```

I am currently using this

```
implode(', ', array_values($car_names))
```

to generate a string like

> Car #1, Car #2, Car #3

I would like to actually get something like

> Car #1, Car #2 and Car #3

The idea would be to insert **" and "** between the two last elements of the array.

If the array happens to contain two key/value pairs (eg, user has 2 cars), there would be no commas.

> Car #1 and Car #2

And if the array contains one key/value (eg, user has 1 car)

> Car #1

Any suggestion how to get this done? I tried using `array_splice` but I'm not sure that's the way to go (ie, inserting a new element into the array).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Search for the last `,` and replace it with `and`.

Comment: @hakre what function could i use for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want something like this, using [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) to get the last element off the end of the array. You can then implode the rest of the array, and add the last element  in a custom fashion:

```
$last_value = array_pop($car_names);
$output = implode(', ', array_values($car_names));
$output .= ($output ? ' and ' : '') . $last_value;
```

Edit: added conditional to check if the array had only one element.

Comment: This fails with array of size 1.

Comment: thx @lonesomeday this works perfectly for what I want - tested with one, 2 and 3 sizes and works OK

Comment: One thing to note about this, `array_pop` removes that last value from the array so if you need the array later it will be missing one item.  A solution to this would be to move this into a function so when the array is passed in as a parameter you are working with a copy of `$car_names` instead of directly with the original array.

Answer (score 6):

```
$last = array_pop($car_names);
echo implode(', ', $car_names) . ' AND ' . $last;
```

Comment: This fails with array of size 1

Comment: @user482594 sure it does, but you got the idea, didn't you ? the idea of SO is not to provide the complete code

Comment: @Teneff Yeah but user will likely select the answer that provides the working code..

Comment: thanks for the support and the votes guys, and user482594 is technically correct, which is the best kind of correct ?

Answer (score 2):

A preg_replace can look for the last command just just swap it to an `and`

```
$yourString = preg_replace( "/, ([\w#]*)$/", "and \1", $yourString );
```

Comment: That sort of thing works in most situations but if the last item in the array contains a comma it will fail.  Unless you can guarantee that the array will never contain an item with a comma in it this method should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a bit longer, but tested for all array sizes and it is a complete solution. Also, it doesn't modify the array like the above answers and is separated into a function.

```
function arrayToString($arr) {
    $count = count($arr);
    if ($count <= 2) {
        return implode(' and ', $arr);
    }
    $result = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if ($i) $result .= ($i == $count - 1) ? ' and ' : ', ';
        $result .= $item;
        $i++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Compacted version with ugly formatting and ignoring good practices like initializing variables:

```
function arrayToString($arr) {
    if (count($arr) <= 2) return implode(' and ', $arr);
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if ($i) $result .= ($i == count($arr) - 1) ? ' and ' : ', ';
        $result .= $item; $i++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a built in function for this, but something like this should work.

```
$last = $car_names[count($car_names)-1];
$implodedString = implode(', ', array_values($car_names))
$implodedString = str_replace(", $last", "and $last", $implodedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an example with the functions named in my comment above:

1. [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) - Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string
2. [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - Return part of a string

and the code:

```
$text = implode(', ', array_values($car_names));
$last = strrpos($text, ',');
if ($last) $text = substr($text, 0, $last-1) . ' AND ' . substr($text, $last+1);
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could do this.  Here's another.

```
<?php
$cars = array('Car #1', 'Car #2', 'Car #3', 'Car #4');
$car = array('Car #1');
$twocars = array('Car #1', 'Car #2');

function arrayToText($arr) {
    switch (count($arr)) {
    case 1:
        return $arr[0];
        break;
    case 2:
        return implode($arr, ' and ');
        break;
    default:
        $last = array_pop($arr);
        return implode($arr, ', ') . ' and ' . $last;
        break;
    }
}

echo '<p>' . arrayToText($cars) . "</p>\n";
echo '<p>' . arrayToText($twocars) . "</p>\n";
echo '<p>' . arrayToText($car) . "</p>\n";
```

**Output**

```
<p>Car #1, Car #2, Car #3 and Array</p>
<p>Car #1 and Car #2</p>
<p>Car #1</p>
```